# Is it possible to start the border-bottom after x amount of pixels?

Tags: css

[image: arrow]

It would be cool if there was such an option, else I'd have to overlap the `border-bottom` with another div..

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: It should be pretty obvious after reading the title and seeing the image.

Comment: @Fabio I know what a border does. I was just checking if there was a css3 option as I've seen people use stuff like gradients on a borders.

Comment: a border starts around the area of a container, not in the middle of nowhere where you want. There's no such option. http://dochub.io/#css/border

Comment: @Fabio I guess thats what it is then :) thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT**: What I'd do these days if there's a bit more in terms of the element's text content is use `box-shadow` and `background-clip`. Otherwise, see the last solution in my original answer.

```css
div {
  border-bottom: solid .75em transparent;
  margin: 7em auto 1em;
  width: 10em; height: 5em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 -1px black;
  background: dimgrey padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Let's dissect the above.

First off, `border-bottom: solid .75em transparent`.

The `border-bottom` area is going to be the gap area. That's why we make it transparent. Changing the width of this border changes the width of the gap.

The `margin`, `width` and `height` rules - nothing strange here, just positioning and sizing the element.

Then we have this bit: `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 -1px black`.

This `box-shadow` with no blur creates the bottom border. The `y` offset (second value) creates a `1px` "border". Increasing this `y` offset increases the width of our "border". This is a `black` border, but we could change that to anything else.

We also don't want our box-shadow to show up on the sides, so we give it a `-1px` spread.

Finally, we set a `background` on our element. It's a `dimgrey` one, but it could be anything else (a gradient, a picture, whatever). By default backgrounds extend under the border as well, but we don't want that, so we limit it to the area of the `padding-box`. I've used the shorthand here. The longhand property is `background-clip` and you can find a detailed explanation for how it works and other examples similar to this one in [**this article**](https://css-tricks.com/the-backgound-clip-property-and-use-cases/) (disclaimer: I wrote it).

---

*Here is the original answer*

You could use a pseudo element. Absolutely positioned, 100% width, offset below the bottom of the element.

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/4474765)

**HTML**:

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    margin: 7em auto 1em;
    width: 10em; height: 5em;
    background: dimgrey;
}
div:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -.8em;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    content: '';
}
```

---

Or you could use `background-clip: content-box` and you won't need to use a pseudo-element. But then your text will stick to the edges of the background (unless it's a small text and centred).

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/4474817)

Relevant **CSS**:

```
div {
    margin: 7em auto 1em;
    padding: 0 0 .8em;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    width: 10em; height: 5em;
    background: dimgrey content-box;
}
```

Comment: this creates a distance between the element and the border?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Difference between margin, padding and border]

Margin and padding are white space around an image or an object.

As you can see in the image, padding is the space between the content and the border that you define, instead margin is the space outside the border, between the border and the other elements next to this object.

So in your case you can do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box{
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here you can find a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/k7QcN/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the padding.

```
padding: 10px; // push 10px the content
border: 1px solid #fff;
```

Comment: Padding just makes the distance between the border and the inner content wider. It doesn't change the border-bottom's offset.