# add border but outside of button in Foundation

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I have this code and I would like to add a solid border outside of the button about 4 pixels away

## in scss

```
.dropdown-button-test {
    @include button(
        $padding : $button-med
    );
    @include dropdown-button(
        $pip-color: $white,
        $base-style: true
    );
    @include button-style(
        $bg : $primary-color,
    )
}
```

## in html

```
<button data-dropdown="drop2" aria-controls="drop2" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-button-test">Custom Dropdown</button><br>
<ul id="drop2" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown" role="menu" aria-hidden="false">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm thinking that wrapping the html code above with another div and putting a css style to it is not a good solution. I wanted to make this button like a template so that all I have to do is add the class dropdown-button-test and all design I want for this custom button will be applied.

Comment: Thanks! The demo helped using outline

Comment: Alternate dupliclate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196214/is-it-possible-to-start-the-border-bottom-after-x-amount-of-pixels

Comment: This was posted way back more than 5 months ago and I mentioned that the person who answered it before helped me accomplish what I want to do. Why is this post being updated? Don't want to see it being down voted.

Comment: Your question isn't getting downvoted (duplicates aren't exactly considered a "bad thing"), but it should have been closed when it was new.  Another user bumped the question, so I added some extra signposts to help future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I need to read more about how stackoverflow works :)